# adding pdf security bookmarks corrupted

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

When I add security to a pdf file the bookmarks becomes corrupted?

> Is there a font that will need to be installed?

[image]

Comment: *"When I add security to a pdf file the bookmarks becomes corrupted?"* - How did you do that? It looks like either the tool or its input were defect.

Comment: 1) What application/program are you using when you see the broken bookmarks? 2) How are you adding the security (code+library)?